# How to get Sitecore 10 certification material?

Tags: certificate, training-certification

I am totally new to Sitecore and would like to get study material for the certification.
Could someone assist me with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can go with the [Sitecore eLearning website](https://learning.sitecore.com/) for `Sitecore 10` Certification material and details. There you will find the `Sitecore 10 .NET Developer Certification Exam`.

**Prerequisites**
This exam is intended for developers. We recommend you meet the following prerequisites before taking the Sitecore 10 .NET Developers Certification Exam:

- At least one year of prior experience developing on the Sitecore XP solution.
- Complete Learning@Sitecore’s Developer’s Fundamentals 9.3 Collection.
- Complete Learning@Sitecore’s Developer’s Fundamentals 10 Collection.
- Complete Learning@Sitecore’s Sitecore Experience Solution Developer 9.1 Instructor-Led Training

*To pass the `Sitecore 10 .NET Developer Certification Exam`, you will also need to be proficient in the exam competencies.* We recommend you prepare by participating in **Learning@Sitecore** training opportunities, enrolling in, and completing our free study guide, reviewing Sitecore’s developer documentation, and speaking with others within the Sitecore development community at large.

**Exam competencies**
To be certified in `Sitecore 10 .NET Developer` you are expected to have fundamental knowledge, skills, and abilities in seven distinct areas, known as competencies:

- Competency 1: Sitecore structure & platform (12%)
- Competency 2: Security & user management (16%)
- Competency 3: Item management (20%)
- Competency 4: Layout & placeholders (10%)
- Competency 5: Components, controls, & renderings (26%)
- Competency 6: Sitecore Content Serialization (10%)
- Competency 7: Containers (6%)

You can also refer below links and youtube video for more insight:

1. [Sitecore 10 Certification Tips and Tricks](https://bala.one/sitecore-10-certification-tips-and-tricks/)
2. [Sitecore 10 .NET Developer Certification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1ic_b7I424)
3. [Sitecore 10 Certification Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kQ8o9ODoQM)

I would personally suggest that you complete the course **Developer's Fundamentals 10 Collection** from the [Sitecore e-learning Portal](https://learning.sitecore.com/). It will make you a better understanding of competencies points 5, 6, and 7 mentioned above.

Comment: It is more similar to Sitecore 9 in terms of questions. Only a few things are extra on containers & serializations.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the helpful points mentioned above, there is a wonderful crash course on Youtube from Sitecore MVP [Navaneethakrishnan (NAVAN) Sundarrajan](https://www.linkedin.com/in/navaneethakrishnansrnna/)
The video link: [Sitecore 10 Certification Crash Course by Navan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kQ8o9ODoQM)